# Converting a SharePoint List Item to form format and print it

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, modern-experience, flow

I want to retrieve an item from a SharePoint Online list (Office 365) and print it out in a form format.

I have looked at a few ways which involve using power automate and third party tools which such as Muhimbi and Encodian to put the item's values into a HTML form template and convert and download the as a PDF.

However this solution requires paying for the third party apps which is extremely expensive.

Is there anyway that I can work around this. Are there any other methods of generating and printing the form with the values of the SharePoint list item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways you can try:

1. Using **SPFx List View command set**:

Check out the [Community demo](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kqLfjOHE3_M) on printing list items using templates with SharePoint Framework list view command set.

**Code Sample**: [Print List Item Command View Set](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-command-print)

2. Using **Power Automate**:

You can use OneDrive for Business action "Convert file" to convert an HTML file to PDF.

**Reference**: [Generate PDF from SharePoint list item](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Generate-PDF-from-SharePoint-list-item/m-p/196543#M20355)